# getIntent().getByteArrayExtra() returns null

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am receiving a NullPointerException error on my getIntent() when trying to pass a bitmap from one activity to an another activity
First Activity

```
public void processor(View view)
{
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)imageCapt.getDrawable();
    Bitmap yeet = drawable.getBitmap();

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yeet.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

    Intent intent = new Intent(camera_activity.this, ClassifierTask.class);
    intent.putExtra("picture", bytes);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Receiving Activity

```
public class ClassifierTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>  {

static Context context;
@Override
public void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

}
@Override
public Void doInBackground(Void... param) {


    Intent intent = ((Activity)context).getIntent();
    byte[] bytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("picture");
    m_bitmapForNn = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0, bytes.length);
```

The error I receive is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.app.Activity.getIntent()' on a null object reference
```

Any advice or solution for this, would be appreciated

Comment: `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Passing a `Bitmap` in an `Intent` extra is going to make your app prone to crashes, as there is a size limit on an `Intent`. It also wastes a lot of memory. Consider consolidating these two activities into one, perhaps using fragments. In terms of your immediate problem, `context` is `null`, apparently. Note that `AsyncTask` will be deprecated next year, and if you used a single activity you would have no need to decode a byte array (let alone do it in a background thread).

Answer (score 0):

I have a very good way

You create a new one Class,and new static

```
public class Data {
    public static byte[] bytes;
}
```

or setup HashMap,ArrayList....

you just put data and read In another place

```
Data.bytes[0]=
```